# JQGrid for JQuery just gives a blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am hoping someone can help as I've been racking my brains on this all morning (I'm sure it's something stupid I've done).

Anyhow I want the data from one of our systems to display in JQGrid, I want the data to load from one page so I'm using the StringXML feature, however I'm having problems in that nothing displays on the page, if I include an alert this displays but the Grid doesn't display even though all files load ok and there are no errors in the error console.

I've pasted the code below, is there anything obivious wrong?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="includes/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="includes/grid/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="includes/grid/js/il8n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/grid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</HEAD><BODY>
<SCRIPT>var liststr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><GRIDDATA><ROWS>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 17:19</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 18:20</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 19:21</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 20:22</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 21:23</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 22:24</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Fri 24 Aug 2012 23:25</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Sat 25 Aug 2012 00:26</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Sat 25 Aug 2012 01:27</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Sat 25 Aug 2012 02:28</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
<ROW><CELL>Sat 25 Aug 2012 03:29</CELL><CELL>5</CELL></ROW>
</ROWS></GRIDDATA>";

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#gridview").jqGrid({ 
            datatype: 'xmlstring', datastr: 'liststr', height: 250, 
            colNames:['Date', 'Lic1'], 
            colModel:[    
                {name:'date',index:'date', width:90, sorttype:'date'}, {name:'30300', index:'30300', width: 200, sorttype:'int'}],
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Licenses in Use"
            })
        ;}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but might it be the uppercase tag names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st: you should have a `<div id="gridview"></div>` and
2nd: in the:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#gridview").jqGrid({ 
            datatype: 'xmlstring', datastr: 'liststr', height: 250, 
            colNames:['Date', 'Lic1'], 
            colModel:[    
                {name:'date',index:'date', width:90, sorttype:'date'}, {name:'30300', index:'30300', width: 200, sorttype:'int'}],
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Licenses in Use"
            })
        ;}
```

you have missed the latest parenthesis of "jQuery(document).ready(" so, your code should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#gridview").jqGrid({ 
            datatype: 'xmlstring', datastr: 'liststr', height: 250, 
            colNames:['Date', 'Lic1'], 
            colModel:[    
                {name:'date',index:'date', width:90, sorttype:'date'}, {name:'30300', index:'30300', width: 200, sorttype:'int'}],
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Licenses in Use"
            });
        });
```

Comment: Many thanks the missing parenthesis certainly didn't help, I found the data issue in the end and something to be aware of everyone make sure your ROW and CELL tags are in LOWERCASE!!!!  If you uppercase them like mine jqGrid it ignores the XMLSTRING data.